# How can we emulate the October 13 basic authentication changes?

Tags: exchange-basicauth

We have a few different options for authentication based on how the client is setup, and basic authentication is the fall through if the others do not work. We'd like to ensure we cover all of our scenarios before that date. How can we set up an environment for testing with the coming changes?